chrome version Version 127.0.6533.120 (Official Build) (64-bit) WebDriver issue
SO i have the chrome version Version 127.0.6533.120 (Official Build) (64-bit). I need to use the webdriver, it only has 127.0.6533.119. what can i do
I tried using the 127.0.6533.119 but of course it did not work. Where can i find the webdriver for my Version 127.0.6533.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)

only major version needs to match. (the 127 part)  Are  you having trouble using that version of the driver?

I have same problem but it's because I'm running Catalina und Chrome updates stopped at 127.0.6533.120. When webdriver_manager tries to update I get OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/Users/simon/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/mac64/127.0.6533.119/chromedriver-mac-x64/THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES.chromedriver' presumably because it's not available ??

above looks like an issue where the manager tries to wildcard find a driver that ends with "chromedriver".  I guess someone released a readme/notice with that as an extension and it's picking the wrong file.  (easy fix is probably rename that THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES file...)

Issue was that the code I'm working on is running on an old machine running Catalina.
Chrome NOT SUPPORTED ANY MORE on Catalina :(
128.0.6613.85 < LAST Catalina supported update!
chromedriver from here Since Chrome will no longer update - chromedriver manager is no longer needed.
Hard coded the path: chromedriver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

There is not yet 127.0.6533.120 chromeDriver ofically released you can try on beta channel if required
Download link - Downlaod from here
Official source - Main page

Is there a link I can use for the chrome-mac-x64 version of chromedriver?

Please provide me versions and architecture you want...looks like version naming different for Mac

In the end I needed 128.0.6613.85 < LAST Catalina supported update!
chromedriver from here Thanks : )

You got it .... It's just hidden...you need to change the url version in existing URL :)

instead of using Version 127.0.6533.120 I used Version 127.0.6533.121 and it worked
version win64
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/127.0.6533.121/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip

there are no problem with webdriver on chrome version. Make sure you install selenium correctly pip install selenium . use below code to see is it working or not.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()

